# Can't pass Date to NSPredicate(format: ...) without "as CVarArg"

Tags: swift, swift3, nsdate, nspredicate, foundation

Is this how I'm supposed to pass a `Date` to `NSPredicate.init(format predicateFormat: String, arguments argList: CVaListPointer)`.

```
let endDate = Date()
NSPredicate(format: "endDate == %@", endDate as CVarArg)
```

It looks kinda clumsy, and I suspect I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `%@` format expect a *Foundation object* as argument, compare
["Predicate Format String Syntax"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) in the "Predicate Programming Guide".

Therefore you have to cast the overlay type `Date` back to its Foundation
counterpart `NSDate`:

```
let endDate = Date()
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "endDate == %@", endDate as NSDate)
```