# How to use NSPredicate with Date type

Tags: swift, nspredicate, foundation

I am trying to make NSPredicate based on a date... I have tried this:

```
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "due_date < %@", Date())
```

I am not sure, but iirc, this worked before?

Now I get this error:

> Argument type 'Date' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'

I tried smth like this

... `Date() as NSDate,`
but that failed too.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the current date as a predicate parameter just create an `NSDate` instance

```
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "due_date < %@", NSDate())
```

For a date variable you can use

```
aDate as NSDate
```

or

```
aDate as CVarArg
```

---

If you get the error

> 'Date?' is not convertible to 'NSDate'

then the code is not the real code because both `Date()` and `NSDate()` are non-optional.

Answer (score 0):

you have to cast the overlay type Date back to its Foundation counterpart `NSDate`:

```
let dueDate = Date()
let pred1 = NSPredicate(format: "due_date < %@", dueDate as NSDate)
```

check this reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39587771/10168919

Comment: I tried that (you can see I mentioned it already in my question). I get 'Date?' is not convertible to 'NSDate'

Comment: It should be work then I just tried it on Playground

Comment: Yeah in playground it works, but it gives me error in Xcode :/ It just doesn't compile.